# Replace character with alphabet depending on position in string

Tags: bash, text-processing, string, timestamps

I have an output like this:

```
(2+05:10)
(10:19)
(00:45)
```

This output represents day hours and minute. 
I would like to replace the ':' with 'd','h' and 'm' respectively,
 to get this

```
2d05h10m
10h19m
00h45m
```

Presently, I tried,

```
 sed -e 's/(//g; s/)//g; s/+/:/g'|awk '{split($0,s,":"); print s[1]"d" s[2]"h"s[3]"m"}')
```

which gives (and here I mess up !)

```
6d05h20m
3d15h17m
1d02h27m
00d08hm
00d11hm
02d25hm
02d30hm
16d50hm
5d00h39m
21d48hm
```

Comment: What have you tried ? It could be done in any scripting language of your choice  and familiarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like

```
< file tr '+:)' dhm | tr -d '('
```

Would do it. Or to match on that pattern more explicitly:

```
sed 's/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\)+\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1d\2h\3m/g
     s/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1h\2m/g' < file
```

Which with some `sed` implementations you can simplify using extended regular expressions to:

```
sed -E 's/\(([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+):([0-9]+)\)/\1d\2h\3m/g
        s/\(([0-9]+):([0-9]+)\)/\1h\2m/g' < file
```

Or with a single `s` command with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{\((?:(\d+)\+)?(\d+):(\d+)\)}{
    ($1 && "$1d") . "$2h$3m"}ge' < file
```

Or:

```
perl -pe 's/\((\d*\+?\d+:\d+\))/$1 =~ y|+:)|dhm|r/ge' < file
```

Comment: `sed 's/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\)+\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1d\2h\3m/g
     s/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1h\2m/g' < file` does not introduce `d  m h` in the string. Could you help.

Comment: @ankit7540, note that it has to be on 2 lines as shown. If you want to put it on one line, you need to separate the 2 `s` commands with a `;`

Answer (score 1):

A simple (but slightly inefficient) perl script should suffice

```
cat output_file | perl simple.pl
```

simple.pl

```
@seps=split /:/,"d:h:m"; 
while(<>) {
 chomp ;
 $_=~s/[\(\)]//g;  #remove braces
 @x = split /:/, $_;   #get parts
 $s="";
 for($i=$#x,$j=$#sep;$i>=0; $i--,$j--) { #iterate on parts and corresponding separator 
    $s=$x[$i].$seps[$j].$s;              #create print string 
 }
 print "$s\n";                           #print this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `awk` solution. Here is one that omits zero elements:

*parse.awk*

```awk
# Start with empty variables
{ d = h = m="" }

# Determine format and set variables accordingly.
# Force numeric interpretation by multiplying by one
NF==5 { d = $2*1; h = $3*1; m = $4*1 }
NF==4 { d = ""  ; h = $2*1; m = $3*1 }

# Only set value if the number is greater than zero
{
  d = d > 0 ? d "d" : ""
  h = h > 0 ? h "h" : ""
  m = m > 0 ? m "m" : ""
}

length(d h m)  > 1 { print d h m }
length(d h m) == 0 { print "Now" }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk -v FS='[()+:]' file
```

Output:

```
2d5h10m
10h19m
45m
```